# Convert multidimensional array to string

Tags: php, mysql

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
 (
  [0] = > 1
  [1] = > 2
  [2] = > 3
  )
 [1] = > Array
 (
  [0] = > 4
  [1] = > 5
  [2] = > 6
  )
 )
```

I have a multidimensional array, I want to convert the inner array to string with this format using php loop statement

```
$array[0] = 1,2,3
$array[1] = 4,5,6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map to a function and implode:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) { return implode(',', $v); }, $array);
```

Comment: where did $v come from?

Comment: $v is the name he gave to the parameter of the function. You can also call it `$value` or `$wateva` as long as you use it in both places.